# Converting from .ply to .pcd format

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, ply-file-format

I have a .ply file and I want to convert it to a .pcd format but not exactly sure how.

I have tried the methods described by the op here [Convertion of .ply format to .pcd format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350493/convertion-of-ply-format-to-pcd-format) but they are not sufficient/doesn't work anymore.

when I try to open the .ply file its just a binary file  except the header which looks something like this:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
comment generated by Cartographer
element vertex 000000207134849
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property float intensity
end_header
bf/B¿ğBè)¿...
...
```

Thus I don't evet know where to start the conversion.

How do I do the conversion ?

Any method/doc would really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I now have a valid solution and therefore answering my question.

I have found this https://github.com/ryanfb/pcl-tools github repo that has a very handy tool called `ply2pcd`

so *basically do the following* to get to conversion form .ply to .pcd

```
git clone https://github.com/ryanfb/pcl-tools 
cmake . 
make 
cd pcl-tools 
chmod +x ply2pcd 
./ply2pcd "path/target.ply" "path/out.pcd"
```

**Note:** You need at least as much RAM as the size of .ply file

Comment: If you use Ubuntu, you can just `apt install pcl-tools`. source: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pcl-tools

Answer (score 2):

I Haven't tried, but something seems to be available in Ubuntu distributions probably doing `sudo apt install pcl-tools`:

- `pcl_ply2pcd` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pcl_ply2pcd.1.html
- `pcl_pcd2ply` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pcl_pcd2ply.1.html

Comment: This one worked for me. Simply use `pcl_ply2pcd input.ply output.pcd`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Open3D library](http://www.open3d.org/), as described here:

> ```
> import open3d as o3d
> pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("source_pointcloud.ply")
> o3d.io.write_point_cloud("sink_pointcloud.pcd", pcd)
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488893/10334964